# eclipse error importing gradle project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gradle, eclipse-neon

I have a Gradle project that includes subprojects defined in setting.gradle file. Some projects are android projects, and others are not. The project builds fine on the command line with the Gradle wrapper.

When importing the project, I chose the root directory that contains build.gradle. Before clicking "Finish", eclipse showed me the expected projects after parsing the Gradle file.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.buildship.core 4 0 2017-07-17 08:32:13.040
!MESSAGE Synchronize Gradle builds with workspace failed due to an unexpected error.
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.DefaultOmniEclipseProjectDependency.from(DefaultOmniEclipseProjectDependency.java:65)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.DefaultOmniEclipseProject$1.apply(DefaultOmniEclipseProject.java:286)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.DefaultOmniEclipseProject$1.apply(DefaultOmniEclipseProject.java:283)
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$8.transform(Iterators.java:794)
    at com.google.common.collect.TransformedIterator.next(TransformedIterator.java:48)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.copyOf(ImmutableList.java:271)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.copyOf(ImmutableList.java:226)
    at com.google.common.collect.FluentIterable.toList(FluentIterable.java:334)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.DefaultOmniEclipseProject.toProjectDependencies(DefaultOmniEclipseProject.java:283)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.DefaultOmniEclipseProject.from(DefaultOmniEclipseProject.java:258)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.DefaultOmniEclipseProject.from(DefaultOmniEclipseProject.java:275)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.DefaultOmniEclipseProject.from(DefaultOmniEclipseProject.java:242)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.DefaultOmniEclipseGradleBuild.from(DefaultOmniEclipseGradleBuild.java:46)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.DefaultSingleBuildModelRepository$8.apply(DefaultSingleBuildModelRepository.java:181)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.DefaultSingleBuildModelRepository$8.apply(DefaultSingleBuildModelRepository.java:177)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.BaseModelRepository.executeAndWait(BaseModelRepository.java:164)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.BaseModelRepository.access$000(BaseModelRepository.java:41)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.BaseModelRepository$2.call(BaseModelRepository.java:121)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4724)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3522)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2315)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2278)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2193)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3932)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4721)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.BaseModelRepository.getFromCache(BaseModelRepository.java:138)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.BaseModelRepository.executeRequest(BaseModelRepository.java:117)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.BaseModelRepository.executeRequest(BaseModelRepository.java:88)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.DefaultSingleBuildModelRepository.fetchEclipseGradleBuild(DefaultSingleBuildModelRepository.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.DefaultModelProvider.fetchEclipseGradleBuild(DefaultModelProvider.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.synchronizeBuild(SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.runToolingApiJob(SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiJob$1.run(ToolingApiJob.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiInvoker.invoke(ToolingApiInvoker.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiJob.run(ToolingApiJob.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Note, Android STudio and IntelliJ aren't IDE options for me due to this outstanding issue:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-122904

Comment: good solution for this is.. start using Android Studio.

Comment: The problem is that IntelliJ and Android Studio currently don't support importing a gradle project that contains android and non-android modules.

And that's just an alternative, that's not a solution to the problem.